# Find a specific URL in the whole web app

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, search

I am looking for a way to find out how many times a specific URL has been used on sites/pages/lists and where exactly it's used.

Example:
I would like to know all places where this link has been used http://collab.sharepoint.com/sites/test/lists/TestList/DispForm.aspx?ID=1 on the whole http://collab.sharepoint.com/ web app.

Is it even possible to achieve this?